# are the usage of うるさい to mean "fussy" and the usage of 草 to mean "substandard" archaic?

Tags: usage, vocabulary, archaic-language

I was thinking what things could be described with  [草 (3) not genuine; substandard;)](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E8%8D%89)

Can we describe someone who is a ゴミ as 草? Like say:

アイツはどうおもう？ くさだ！

Or is the　"substandard" meaning of 草 already "phased out" ?

Also, is the usage of うるさい to mean "fussy" archaic / "phased out"?

Like let's say I say メシにうるさくするんな！

Does it simply sound weird (like i'm some old grandpa)?

Comment: @Pacerier: I fail to see the connection between your title and the rest of your question. Are you asking about くさ or うるさい??

Comment: Maybe you meant くそ, not くさ ;)

Comment: @Dave sry my mistake. edited

Comment: @Lukman no i meant the 草 (くさ) at http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1MUE%E8%8D%89

Comment: Do you think that the two questions which you are asking are related?  If not, please do not mix two unrelated questions into one.

Comment: You are asking two unrelated questions here, making it difficult for one person to provide the best answer.  Closed.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi ok i'll split them next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title and the body seem to ask two different questions, but I'll answer them both.

「うるさい」 as 'fussy' is not at all archaic. 彼はラーメンにうるさいからいい店を知っている。

On the other hand, in all my years of speaking with Japanese friends and family, I have never heard of using 草 as a derogative.

Comment: heys sry my mistake just now. had edited the question.

Comment: Does that example translate as "He is particular about his ramen, so he knows a good (ramen) shop"?  Or maybe singular/plural of shop is ambiguous?

Comment: @Muhd: yes, that's correct, and yes, in the example the singular/plural of shop/店 is ambiguous. It could go either way between "he knows a good ramen shop" and "he knows good ramen shops".

Answer (score 2):

As for 草, as a **prefix** it means "informal". I suppose that meaning can overlap with "substandard" but it's not taken to be derogatory.

My dictionary (旺文社国語辞典) gives these examples:　草競馬、草野球、草芝居、草相撲